# How To Take RTSP Stream and push that stream to an HTML5 client?

Tags: python, opencv, webrtc, html5-video, rtsp

To keep it simple I'm trying to copy the functionality of this project to use in my own: https://github.com/deepch/RTSPtoWebRTC

Using Go. this program takes an RTSP stream and redirects the raw stream data to a port,
then it generates an SDP packet that a WebRTC client consumes through POST and grabs the video. This results in instant streaming, with no noticeable latency.

Trying to implement this in python has proven to be very difficult. So far the only way I can see to interact with RTSP is to use OpenCV and I can't figure out a way to get the raw stream data from it.

I could some tips on libraries on use that do exactly that, take an RTSP stream and prepare it for WebRTC Travel, really anything.

Comment: Found another project that does part of what I want, this has examples for how to get raw RTSP data, I can probably figure out a way to integrate that with RTC: https://github.com/gabrieljablonski/rtsp-rtp-stream